# Java SWT with maven Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite

Tags: java, linux, swt

I am trying to create an standalone app with java, maven and swt. It builds but when I try to run it, I get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ec.com.puce.maestria.comunicacion</groupId>
    <artifactId>fibra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ec.com.puce.maestria.comunicacion.principal.Fibra</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>swt repo</id>
            <url>http://swt-maven.googlecode.com/git-history/master/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Do I need to do something else with eclipse so it loads properly the swt libraries?  What do i need to do for the JVM to recognize swt, isnt maven supposed to pack swt on my jar or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>swt-repo</id>
        <url>https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then you might have more luck with the dependcy:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```